# Is creating a new List to modify a collection in a for each loop a design flaw?

Tags: c#

I recently ran in to this common invalid operation `Collection was modified` in C#, and while I understand it fully, it seems to be such a common problem (google, about 300k results!). But it also seems to be a logical and straightforward thing to modify a list while you go through it.

```
List<Book> myBooks = new List<Book>();

public void RemoveAllBooks(){
    foreach(Book book in myBooks){
         RemoveBook(book);
    }
}

RemoveBook(Book book){
    if(myBooks.Contains(book)){
         myBooks.Remove(book);
         if(OnBookEvent != null)
            OnBookEvent(this, new EventArgs("Removed"));
    }
}
```

Some people will create another list to iterate through, but this is just dodging the issue. What's the real solution, or what is the actual design issue here? We all seem to *want* to do this, but is it indicative of a design flaw?

Comment: You can use an iterator or remove from the end of the list.

Comment: @ElDuderino https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx. Don't miss the `You consume an iterator from client code by using a For Each…Next (Visual Basic) or foreach (C#) statement` line

Comment: In Java there are `Iterator` (works as you described) and `ListIterator` (works as you desire). This would point that in order to provide iterator functionality over a wide range of collections types and implementations, `Iterator` is extremely restrictive (what happens if you delete a node in a balanced tree? Does `next()` make sense anymore), with `ListIterator` being more powerful due to having less use cases.

Comment: @SJuan76 in other languages there are still more iterator types, e.g. C++ has forward iterators (equivalent to Java's Iterator), bidirectional iterators (like ListIterator), random access iterators, input iterators (like a Java Iterator that doesn't support the optional operations) and output iterators (i.e. write-only, which is more useful than it sounds).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is creating a new List to modify a collection in a for each loop a design flaw?

The short answer: *no*

Simply spoken, you produce *undefined* behaviour, when you iterate through a collection and modify it at the same time. Think of *deleting* the `next` element in a sequence. What would happen, if `MoveNext()` is called?

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and its behavior is undefined.
>   The enumerator does not have exclusive access to the collection; therefore, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure.

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwyysy67(v=vs.110).aspx)

By the way, you could shorten your `RemoveAllBooks` to simply `return new List<Book>()`

And to remove a book, I recommend returning a filtred collection:

`return books.Where(x => x.Author != "Bob").ToList();`

A possible shelf-implementation would look like:

```
public class Shelf
{
    List<Book> books=new List<Book> {
        new Book ("Paul"),
        new Book ("Peter")
    };

    public IEnumerable<Book> getAllBooks(){
        foreach(Book b in books){
            yield return b;
        }
    }

    public void RemovePetersBooks(){
        books= books.Where(x=>x.Author!="Peter").ToList();
    }

    public void EmptyShelf(){
        books = new List<Book> ();
    }

    public Shelf ()
    {
    }
}

public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Shelf s = new Shelf ();
    foreach (Book b in s.getAllBooks()) {
        Console.WriteLine (b.Author);
    }
    s.RemovePetersBooks ();

    foreach (Book b in s.getAllBooks()) {
        Console.WriteLine (b.Author);
    }
    s.EmptyShelf ();
    foreach (Book b in s.getAllBooks()) {
        Console.WriteLine (b.Author);
    }
}
```

Comment: You contradict yourself when you answer yes and then provide an example which also creates a new list. Other than that i agree.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen you are right :D I was thinking of modifying as a flaw ...

Answer (score 6):

Creating a new list to modify it is a good solution to the problem that existing iterators of the list cannot reliably continue after the change unless they know how the list has changed.

Another solution is to make the modification using the iterator rather than through the list interface itself. This only works if there can only be one iterator - it doesn't solve the problem for multiple threads iterating over the list concurrently, which (as long as accessing stale data is acceptable) creating a new list does.

An alternative solution that the framework implementers could have taken is to have the list track all its iterators and notify them when changes occur. However, thw overheads of this approach are high - for it to work in general with multiple threads, all iterator operations would need to lock the list (to ensure it doesn't change while the operation is in progress), which would make all list operations slow. There would also be nontrivial memory overhead, plus it requires the runtime to support soft references, and IIRC the first version of the CLR didn't.

From a different perspective, copying the list to modify it allows you to use LINQ  to specify the modification, which generally results in clearer code than directly iterating over the list, IMO.